# Which Java-library can be used to access data via WebDAV?

Tags: java, webdav

That's the question: Which library can help me to access data available via WebDAV in my Java-programs? OpenSource is preferred.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The now deprecated [Apache Jakarta Slide](http://jakarta.apache.org/slide/) project includes a Java [WebDAV client library](http://jakarta.apache.org/slide/clientjavadoc/index.html) - but this project is retired due to the lack of a developer community.

[Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) is mentioned as alternative to Slide. You might want to check if its [WebDAV library](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html) can be used instead.

If you just want to access files from a WebDAV repository, you can simply use a HTTP library as WebDAV builds upon HTTP. You only need a WebDAV client library if you want to use WebDAV features like locking, directory listings or access to properties (meta-data).

Comment: I need access to the properties. But the Jackrabbit-library sounds good, I will take a look, if it is usable. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: None of the link are valid anymore.

Comment: Apache Jackrabbit WebDAV Library moved to https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/components/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html

Answer (score 16):

I created a very easy to use java webdav client: http://sardine.googlecode.com/

This now moved to github :  https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine

Answer (score 9):

Libraries which are already around for a while are:

- [Miltion WebDav](http://milton.io/)
- [JackRabbit WebDav](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/components/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html)
- [Apache wink WebDav extension](http://wink.apache.org/1.0/html/5.6%20WebDAV%20Extension.html)

Milton requires license when DAV 2 is required.

On [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebDAV_software) you find a a small summary of available libraries.

Answer (score 5):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdavclient4j/ is based on the retired Apache Jakarta Slide project's Java webdav client, and includes the VFS WebDAV provider. It is packaged with HttpClient 3.0.1.

Comment: +1 The client library of Jakarta Slide was good and Jackrabbit doesn't offer anything equivalent. It's good to know there is something new in this field.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a better library to use for webdav operations. It's called Sardine hosted in Google Code.

https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine (was previously http://code.google.com/p/sardine)

I found it through here:
[Java: How to upload a file to a WebDAV server from a servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261507/java-how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-webdav-server-from-a-servlet)

Comment: This has many contributors and is still an active project 5 years after the answer above was posted, so it looks like a useful option.

Answer (score 3):

Never used it, but maybe apache commons [vfs](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/)?

Answer (score 2):

[Apache's Jakarta Project](http://jakarta.apache.org/) has a [WebDav Construction Kit](http://jakarta.apache.org/slide/wck.html), which should fit this need.

Comment: WebDav Construction Kit looks like a server side technology for implementing WebDav in Tomcat or other containers.  Am I wrong?