# Java: How to upload a file to a WebDAV server from a servlet?

Tags: java, webdav

my ajax application uploads a file to a Java application container from the user's browser. What I'd like to do is this: once the uploading has completed I want to "send" the file to a WebDAV server, identified by the host name (i.e. localhost), the port (i.e. 8080) and the location where I want to store the file (i.e. dir1/dir2).

What I am after is basically a WebDAV client framework that enables me to upload a file to WebDAV. In my application I am already using "webdavclient4j", but I don't seem to find a way to upload a file with it?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help you might provide.

F

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with only a few lines of code using my recently released and super easy to use modern webdav client for java, Sardine. Here is a couple examples (first one uses commons-io to read the file):

```
Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin("username", "password");
byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("/file/on/disk"));
sardine.put("http://yourdavserver.com/adirectory/nameOfFile.jpg", data);
```

or using streams:

```
Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin("username", "password");
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/some/file/on/disk.txt"));
sardine.put("http://yourdavserver.com/adirectory/nameOfFile.jpg", fis);
```

https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine

cheers,

jon

Comment: Hi Jon,

thanks for your response. I tried Sardine and decided to use it in my applications. Makes things much easier. 

F

Comment: I too implemented Sardine.  Amazingly simple to create a webservice from -- now I just have to get it all tested ;)

Comment: @Jon: Is there a way to directly upload a directory? And if there is a directory present on the webserver, would it just overwrite the files?

Comment: Uploading an entire directory is the same as uploading a bunch of individual files. Sardine allows you to both upload individual files as well as check to see if something is present on the server.

Comment: Hi Jon, I need to upload documents using a SSL certificate, I read the wiki but I'm not able to figure how to link between KeyStore and SSLSocketFactory https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/wiki/UsageGuide#ssl

Comment: Sardine API looks pretty friendly, but it fails to work with a particular Oracle server (with error like no response from server). Although web browsers and Apache Jackrabbit can handle it.

Comment: I could not create a new directory with sardine, createdirectory uses MKCOL verb but it does not work. is there another way to create a directory?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Jackrabbit WebDAV Library](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html).

An example of a WebDAV client to upload content to a WebDAV server (taken from [here](http://indiwiz.com/2009/02/11/webdav-client-in-java/)):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.InputStreamRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.client.methods.PutMethod;

...

// WebDAV URL:
final String baseUrl = ...;
// Source file to upload:
File f = ...;
try{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
    client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

    PutMethod method = new PutMethod(baseUrl + "/" + f.getName());
    RequestEntity requestEntity = new InputStreamRequestEntity(
        new FileInputStream(f));
    method.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
    client.executeMethod(method);
    System.out.println(method.getStatusCode() + " " + method.getStatusText());
}
catch(HttpException ex){
    // Handle Exception
}
catch(IOException ex){
    // Handle Exception
}
```

Comment: I tried and tried to get the code working you have posted.  It caused no end of grief with Tomcat.  Our WebDAV server is based on Jackrabbit so I really wanted that to work.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me with an Oracle webdav server (unlike Sardine).