# How to download File from File Hosts using Java

Tags: java

Cant get a direct download Link from a File Host

I want to download a File from a File Host like Workupload or Google Drive, but as far as i know the url must be a direct link to the file like this: `https://some.url/files/file.txt`
But File Hosts only provide Links for Web Browsers: `https://workupload.com/file/someFile`
I already tried to use the firefox dev tools to get direct link but that link also doesnt work, it only directs to a sub domain `f59.workupload.com`
My Code:

```
        if (!dataFile.exists()) {
        try {
            fetchWebsite = new URL("URL");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(fetchWebsite.openStream());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile)) {
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It downloads fine, the file is just a html page thats the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about Workupload, but Google Drive should be accessible via [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV). As that, use client libraries as suggested in

- [Java WebDAV client side library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672678/java-webdav-client-side-library)
- [Which Java-library can be used to access data via WebDAV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122685/which-java-library-can-be-used-to-access-data-via-webdav)